# How to change Date Format in mysql Command

Tags: mysql

I want to change date format in MySQL command line.

```
create table date(date Date);
```

My date comes from as string like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

I want them to be in format:

```
YYYY
```

How can I do this with mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) function in mysql for YYYY. Please read up on it's formatting/how it works.

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a `YEAR` type available in MySQL. In this case you could use:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (yourcolumn YEAR);
```

See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/year.html) for details.

You can use `YEAR()` [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) to extract only year from a `date`/`datetime` column. e.g.

```
SELECT YEAR(yourcolumn) FROM yourtable;
```